# Why does Firefox 13 not display images?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When using photo.SE in Firefox 13 I cannot see images such as the PoW image.

This is what I see:
[image]

It also doesnt display pictures in questions and answers.

thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have accidentally blocked all image contents from Photo.SE. Please go to **Options > Content > Load images automatically > Exceptions** and check for any entry which might have caused the problem.